# how much does index effect performance (CPU) when execute batch insert in mongo

Tags: mongodb, indexing, cpu-usage, batch-insert

Recently , I found a spike cpu use(over 200%-400% ) in our `standalone mongo(4.2.2 version)` which deployed with docker on a 16g , 6 core cpu machine .

```
[root@localhost ~]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        6.1G        1.0G         17M        8.4G        9.0G
Swap:           11G        528M         11G
```

```
top - 14:02:41 up 54 days, 21:50,  0 users,  load average: 2.25, 1.06, 0.80
Tasks:   9 total,   1 running,   8 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 75.4 us,  2.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 20.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.8 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16266496 total,   203948 free,  6697376 used,  9365172 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 12386300 total, 11849724 free,   536576 used.  9212400 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 mongodb   20   0 5431804 3.403g   9344 S 441.2 21.9  26714:21 mongod
 2300 root      20   0 1005132  10320   4476 S   0.7  0.1   0:00.49 mongostat
 1023 root      20   0   18492   2136   1672 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 bash
 1404 root      20   0   18600   2140   1676 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 bash
 1615 root      20   0   18496   2124   1672 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 bash
 1662 root      20   0   38856   2064   1396 S   0.0  0.0   3:31.04 top
 1952 root      20   0   18496   2156   1680 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 bash
 2255 root      20   0   18496   2128   1660 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 bash
 2319 root      20   0   38724   1812   1308 R   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 top
```

Later we figured out it was the `batch insert operation (unorder)` that cause the problem , more specifically , is the index created on collection that we operate on . I say so because i drop the index and cpu usage drop to 50% , and back to 200-300% when i recreate it (still with batch insert enable). Down below is a fraction of my mongostat result

```
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize   res qrw arw net_in net_out conn                time
   554    *0   1036     *0       0     3|0  6.5% 79.5%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0   548k   62.5k   60 Nov 25 14:02:58.107
   769     2   2599     *0       2     2|0  6.3% 79.4%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0   925k    869k   60 Nov 25 14:02:59.109
   555    72   1049     *0       6     4|0  6.2% 79.3%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0   646k    547k   60 Nov 25 14:03:00.107
   720   514   1985     *0      72     0|0  5.9% 79.3%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0  1.66m   5.64m   60 Nov 25 14:03:01.107
   553    40   2735     *0       7     2|0  5.6% 79.1%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0  1.01m    863k   60 Nov 25 14:03:02.109
   438     3   1379     *0       3     1|0  5.3% 78.9%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0   561k    854k   60 Nov 25 14:03:03.107
   143    *0    892     *0       0     6|0  5.0% 78.8%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0   198k   48.4k   60 Nov 25 14:03:04.108
    *0    96    404     *0       9     7|0  4.7% 78.7%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0   197k   1.47m   60 Nov 25 14:03:05.108
  1699   530   2325     *0      77     3|0  5.4% 79.0%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0  2.69m   5.54m   60 Nov 25 14:03:06.107
   874     2   3640     *0       2     1|0  5.4% 78.9%       0 5.18G 3.40G 0|0 1|0  1.02m    874k   60 Nov 25 14:03:07.107
```

The index i mentions above is a single field index , and i really dont know why the index has such a huge impact on the cpu usage . From my point of view , insert operation consumer I/O rather than cpu . If mongo should traverse the index to locate the exact position to insert new document , then the number inserted isn't really big(around 1000 , seem from mongostat) , and i dont think mongo could't process it properly and thus has such a huge overhead on cpu

```
db.getCollection("mycollection").createIndex({code:1});
```

Im not familiar with mongo , maybe i miss or misunderstand something really happen during mongo insert operation with index. And i dont know if there is some setting or variable to help to tune the performance. Thanks advanced if anyone knows how to fix this problem !!!

**New Edit: supply some info**

no strange docker restriction to mongo

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --restart always -v /data/mongo1/db:/data/db -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime --name mongo1 -m 8G -d mongo
```

thread info during high cpu usage period

```
top - 10:25:59 up 55 days, 18:13,  0 users,  load average: 2.29, 2.62, 2.04
Threads:  99 total,   5 running,  94 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 76.3 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 19.8 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.8 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16266496 total,   742292 free,  5017916 used, 10506288 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 12386300 total, 11807484 free,   578816 used. 10891612 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   31 mongodb   20   0 5431804 1.772g   9228 R 99.7 11.4   3301:11 mongod
   33 mongodb   20   0 5431804 1.772g   9228 R 99.3 11.4   3619:33 mongod
   34 mongodb   20   0 5431804 1.772g   9228 R 99.0 11.4   3506:26 mongod
   38 mongodb   20   0 5431804 1.772g   9228 R 96.7 11.4   1034:06 WTCheck.tThread
   32 mongodb   20   0 5431804 1.772g   9228 S 16.6 11.4   3625:46 mongod
 2450 mongodb   20   0 5431804 1.772g   9228 S  3.0 11.4   0:21.02 conn1431
 2462 mongodb   20   0 5431804 1.772g   9228 S  2.7 11.4   0:59.76 conn1443
 2452 mongodb   20   0 5431804 1.772g   9228 S  2.3 11.4   0:53.96 conn1433
```

I set slow log threshold to 50 ms, and get some slow log related to insert

```
db.getCollection("").insert( {
    op: "insert",
    ns: "stock_market_a.t_a_stock_trade12",
    command: {
        insert: "t_a_stock_trade12",
        ordered: false,
        $db: "stock_market_a"
    },
    ninserted: NumberInt("1"),
    keysInserted: NumberInt("2"),
    numYield: NumberInt("0"),
    locks: {
        ParallelBatchWriterMode: {
            acquireCount: {
                r: NumberLong("2")
            }
        },
        ReplicationStateTransition: {
            acquireCount: {
                w: NumberLong("2")
            }
        },
        Global: {
            acquireCount: {
                r: NumberLong("1"),
                w: NumberLong("1")
            }
        },
        Database: {
            acquireCount: {
                w: NumberLong("1")
            }
        },
        Collection: {
            acquireCount: {
                w: NumberLong("1")
            }
        },
        Mutex: {
            acquireCount: {
                r: NumberLong("2")
            }
        }
    },
    flowControl: {
        acquireCount: NumberLong("1")
    },
    storage: { },
    responseLength: NumberInt("45"),
    protocol: "op_msg",
    millis: NumberInt("100"),
    ts: ISODate("2021-11-26T02:54:46.171Z"),
    client: "192.168.1.128",
    allUsers: [ ],
    user: ""
} );
```

Down below are server parameters info obtained by executing `db.adminCommand( { getParameter: '*'} )` . Here I did change maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes to 2048 ,and keep other default setting unchange , but it didn't solve the problem .

```
db.getCollection("").insert( {
    AlwaysRecordTraffic: "",
    KeysRotationIntervalSec: NumberInt("7776000"),
    ShardingTaskExecutorPoolHostTimeoutMS: NumberInt("300000"),
    ShardingTaskExecutorPoolMaxConnecting: NumberInt("2"),
    ShardingTaskExecutorPoolMaxSize: NumberInt("32767"),
    ShardingTaskExecutorPoolMinSize: NumberInt("1"),
    ShardingTaskExecutorPoolRefreshRequirementMS: NumberInt("60000"),
    ShardingTaskExecutorPoolRefreshTimeoutMS: NumberInt("20000"),
    ShardingTaskExecutorPoolReplicaSetMatching: "matchPrimaryNode",
    TransactionRecordMinimumLifetimeMinutes: NumberInt("30"),
    adaptiveServiceExecutorIdlePctThreshold: NumberInt("60"),
    adaptiveServiceExecutorMaxQueueLatencyMicros: NumberInt("500"),
    adaptiveServiceExecutorRecursionLimit: NumberInt("8"),
    adaptiveServiceExecutorReservedThreads: NumberInt("-1"),
    adaptiveServiceExecutorRunTimeJitterMillis: NumberInt("500"),
    adaptiveServiceExecutorRunTimeMillis: NumberInt("5000"),
    adaptiveServiceExecutorStuckThreadTimeoutMillis: NumberInt("250"),
    allowRolesFromX509Certificates: true,
    allowSecondaryReadsDuringBatchApplication: true,
    authSchemaVersion: NumberInt("5"),
    authenticationMechanisms: [
        "MONGODB-X509",
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ],
    authorizationManagerCacheSize: NumberInt("100"),
    authorizationManagerPinnedUsers: [ ],
    authorizationManagerPinnedUsersRefreshIntervalMillis: NumberLong("1000"),
    bgSyncOplogFetcherBatchSize: NumberInt("13981010"),
    cachePressureThreshold: NumberInt("95"),
    checkCachePressurePeriodSeconds: NumberInt("5"),
    clientCursorMonitorFrequencySecs: NumberInt("4"),
    cloudFreeMonitoringEndpointURL: "https://cloud.mongodb.com/freemonitoring/mongo",
    clusterAuthMode: "undefined",
    collectionClonerBatchSize: NumberInt("0"),
    collectionClonerUsesExhaust: true,
    connPoolMaxConnsPerHost: NumberInt("200"),
    connPoolMaxInUseConnsPerHost: NumberInt("2147483647"),
    connPoolMaxShardedConnsPerHost: NumberInt("200"),
    connPoolMaxShardedInUseConnsPerHost: NumberInt("2147483647"),
    createRollbackDataFiles: true,
    cursorTimeoutMillis: NumberLong("600000"),
    diagnosticDataCollectionDirectoryPath: "/data/db/diagnostic.data",
    diagnosticDataCollectionDirectorySizeMB: NumberInt("200"),
    diagnosticDataCollectionEnabled: true,
    diagnosticDataCollectionFileSizeMB: NumberInt("10"),
    diagnosticDataCollectionPeriodMillis: NumberInt("1000"),
    diagnosticDataCollectionSamplesPerChunk: NumberInt("300"),
    diagnosticDataCollectionSamplesPerInterimUpdate: NumberInt("10"),
    disableIndexSpecNamespaceGeneration: false,
    disableJavaScriptJIT: true,
    disableLogicalSessionCacheRefresh: false,
    disableNonSSLConnectionLogging: false,
    disableNonTLSConnectionLogging: false,
    disabledSecureAllocatorDomains: [ ],
    enableElectionHandoff: true,
    enableFlowControl: true,
    enableHybridIndexBuilds: true,
    enableIndexBuildsCoordinatorForCreateIndexesCommand: false,
    enableLocalhostAuthBypass: true,
    enableTestCommands: false,
    failIndexKeyTooLong: true,
    featureCompatibilityVersion: {
        version: "4.2"
    },
    flowControlDecayConstant: 0.5,
    flowControlFudgeFactor: 0.95,
    flowControlMaxSamples: NumberInt("1000000"),
    flowControlMinTicketsPerSecond: NumberInt("100"),
    flowControlSamplePeriod: NumberInt("1000"),
    flowControlTargetLagSeconds: NumberInt("10"),
    flowControlThresholdLagPercentage: 0.5,
    flowControlTicketAdderConstant: NumberInt("1000"),
    flowControlTicketMultiplierConstant: 1.05,
    flowControlWarnThresholdSeconds: NumberInt("10"),
    forceRollbackViaRefetch: false,
    globalConnPoolIdleTimeoutMinutes: NumberInt("2147483647"),
    heapProfilingEnabled: false,
    heapProfilingSampleIntervalBytes: NumberLong("262144"),
    honorSystemUmask: false,
    initialSyncOplogBuffer: "collection",
    initialSyncOplogBufferPeekCacheSize: NumberInt("10000"),
    initialSyncOplogFetcherBatchSize: NumberInt("13981010"),
    internalDocumentSourceCursorBatchSizeBytes: NumberInt("4194304"),
    internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes: NumberLong("104857600"),
    internalDocumentSourceLookupCacheSizeBytes: NumberInt("104857600"),
    internalDocumentSourceSortMaxBlockingSortBytes: NumberLong("104857600"),
    internalGeoNearQuery2DMaxCoveringCells: NumberInt("16"),
    internalGeoPredicateQuery2DMaxCoveringCells: NumberInt("16"),
    internalInsertMaxBatchSize: NumberInt("64"),
    internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes: NumberLong("104857600"),
    internalProhibitShardOperationRetry: false,
    internalQueryAllowShardedLookup: false,
    internalQueryAlwaysMergeOnPrimaryShard: false,
    internalQueryCacheDisableInactiveEntries: false,
    internalQueryCacheEvictionRatio: 10,
    internalQueryCacheFeedbacksStored: NumberInt("20"),
    internalQueryCacheListPlansNewOutput: false,
    internalQueryCacheSize: NumberInt("5000"),
    internalQueryCacheWorksGrowthCoefficient: 2,
    internalQueryDisableExchange: false,
    internalQueryEnumerationMaxIntersectPerAnd: NumberInt("3"),
    internalQueryEnumerationMaxOrSolutions: NumberInt("10"),
    internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: NumberInt("33554432"),
    internalQueryExecYieldIterations: NumberInt("128"),
    internalQueryExecYieldPeriodMS: NumberInt("10"),
    internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes: NumberInt("104857600"),
    internalQueryForceIntersectionPlans: false,
    internalQueryIgnoreUnknownJSONSchemaKeywords: false,
    internalQueryMaxScansToExplode: NumberInt("200"),
    internalQueryPlanEvaluationCollFraction: 0.3,
    internalQueryPlanEvaluationMaxResults: NumberInt("101"),
    internalQueryPlanEvaluationWorks: NumberInt("10000"),
    internalQueryPlanOrChildrenIndependently: true,
    internalQueryPlannerEnableHashIntersection: false,
    internalQueryPlannerEnableIndexIntersection: true,
    internalQueryPlannerGenerateCoveredWholeIndexScans: false,
    internalQueryPlannerMaxIndexedSolutions: NumberInt("64"),
    internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS: false,
    internalQueryProhibitMergingOnMongoS: false,
    internalQueryS2GeoCoarsestLevel: NumberInt("0"),
    internalQueryS2GeoFinestLevel: NumberInt("23"),
    internalQueryS2GeoMaxCells: NumberInt("20"),
    internalValidateFeaturesAsMaster: true,
    javascriptProtection: false,
    journalCommitInterval: NumberInt("100"),
    jsHeapLimitMB: NumberInt("1100"),
    localLogicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: NumberInt("30"),
    logComponentVerbosity: {
        verbosity: NumberInt("0"),
        accessControl: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        command: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        control: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        executor: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        geo: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        index: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        network: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1"),
            asio: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            },
            bridge: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            },
            connectionPool: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            }
        },
        query: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        replication: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1"),
            election: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            },
            heartbeats: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            },
            initialSync: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            },
            rollback: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            }
        },
        sharding: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1"),
            shardingCatalogRefresh: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            }
        },
        storage: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1"),
            recovery: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            },
            journal: {
                verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
            }
        },
        write: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        ftdc: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        tracking: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        },
        transaction: {
            verbosity: NumberInt("-1")
        }
    },
    logLevel: NumberInt("0"),
    logicalSessionRefreshMillis: NumberInt("300000"),
    maxAcceptableLogicalClockDriftSecs: NumberLong("31536000"),
    maxBSONDepth: NumberInt("200"),
    maxIndexBuildDrainBatchSize: NumberInt("1000"),
    maxIndexBuildDrainMemoryUsageMegabytes: NumberInt("16"),
    maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes: NumberInt("2048"),
    maxLogSizeKB: NumberInt("10"),
    maxNumberOfTransactionOperationsInSingleOplogEntry: NumberInt("2147483647"),
    maxOplogTruncationPointsAfterStartup: NumberLong("100"),
    maxOplogTruncationPointsDuringStartup: NumberLong("100"),
    maxSessions: NumberInt("1000000"),
    maxSyncSourceLagSecs: NumberInt("30"),
    maxTargetSnapshotHistoryWindowInSeconds: NumberInt("5"),
    maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis: NumberInt("5"),
    migrateCloneInsertionBatchDelayMS: NumberInt("0"),
    migrateCloneInsertionBatchSize: NumberInt("0"),
    migrationLockAcquisitionMaxWaitMS: NumberInt("500"),
    minMillisBetweenSnapshotWindowDec: NumberInt("500"),
    minMillisBetweenSnapshotWindowInc: NumberInt("500"),
    minOplogTruncationPoints: NumberLong("10"),
    notablescan: false,
    numInitialSyncAttempts: NumberInt("10"),
    numInitialSyncCollectionCountAttempts: NumberInt("3"),
    numInitialSyncCollectionFindAttempts: NumberInt("3"),
    numInitialSyncConnectAttempts: NumberInt("10"),
    numInitialSyncListCollectionsAttempts: NumberInt("3"),
    numInitialSyncListDatabasesAttempts: NumberInt("3"),
    numInitialSyncListIndexesAttempts: NumberInt("3"),
    numInitialSyncOplogFindAttempts: NumberInt("3"),
    opensslCipherConfig: "",
    opensslDiffieHellmanParameters: "",
    oplogFetcherInitialSyncMaxFetcherRestarts: NumberInt("10"),
    oplogFetcherSteadyStateMaxFetcherRestarts: NumberInt("1"),
    oplogInitialFindMaxSeconds: NumberInt("60"),
    oplogRetriedFindMaxSeconds: NumberInt("2"),
    oplogTruncationPointSizeMB: NumberInt("0"),
    orphanCleanupDelaySecs: NumberInt("900"),
    periodicNoopIntervalSecs: NumberInt("10"),
    priorityTakeoverFreshnessWindowSeconds: NumberInt("2"),
    quiet: false,
    rangeDeleterBatchDelayMS: NumberInt("20"),
    rangeDeleterBatchSize: NumberInt("0"),
    recoverFromOplogAsStandalone: false,
    replBatchLimitBytes: NumberInt("104857600"),
    replBatchLimitOperations: NumberInt("5000"),
    replElectionTimeoutOffsetLimitFraction: 0.15,
    replWriterThreadCount: NumberInt("16"),
    reportOpWriteConcernCountersInServerStatus: false,
    reservedServiceExecutorRecursionLimit: NumberInt("8"),
    roleGraphInvalidationIsFatal: false,
    rollbackRemoteOplogQueryBatchSize: NumberInt("2000"),
    rollbackTimeLimitSecs: NumberInt("86400"),
    saslHostName: "04d109525aa0",
    saslServiceName: "mongodb",
    saslauthdPath: "",
    scramIterationCount: NumberInt("10000"),
    scramSHA256IterationCount: NumberInt("15000"),
    scriptingEngineInterruptIntervalMS: NumberInt("1000"),
    shardedConnPoolIdleTimeoutMinutes: NumberInt("2147483647"),
    skipCorruptDocumentsWhenCloning: false,
    skipShardingConfigurationChecks: false,
    skipShellCursorFinalize: false,
    snapshotWindowAdditiveIncreaseSeconds: NumberInt("2"),
    snapshotWindowMultiplicativeDecrease: 0.75,
    sslMode: "disabled",
    sslWithholdClientCertificate: false,
    startupAuthSchemaValidation: true,
    suppressNoTLSPeerCertificateWarning: false,
    syncdelay: 60,
    synchronousServiceExecutorRecursionLimit: NumberInt("8"),
    takeUnstableCheckpointOnShutdown: false,
    taskExecutorPoolSize: NumberInt("1"),
    tcmallocAggressiveMemoryDecommit: NumberInt("0"),
    tcmallocMaxTotalThreadCacheBytes: NumberLong("1073741824"),
    testingSnapshotBehaviorInIsolation: false,
    tlsMode: "disabled",
    tlsWithholdClientCertificate: false,
    traceExceptions: false,
    traceWriteConflictExceptions: false,
    trafficRecordingDirectory: "",
    transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds: NumberInt("60"),
    transactionSizeLimitBytes: NumberLong("9223372036854775807"),
    ttlMonitorEnabled: true,
    ttlMonitorSleepSecs: NumberInt("60"),
    useReadOnceCursorsForIndexBuilds: true,
    waitForSecondaryBeforeNoopWriteMS: NumberInt("10"),
    waitForStepDownOnNonCommandShutdown: true,
    watchdogPeriodSeconds: NumberInt("-1"),
    wiredTigerConcurrentReadTransactions: NumberInt("128"),
    wiredTigerConcurrentWriteTransactions: NumberInt("128"),
    wiredTigerCursorCacheSize: NumberInt("-100"),
    wiredTigerEngineRuntimeConfig: "",
    wiredTigerFileHandleCloseIdleTime: NumberInt("100000"),
    wiredTigerFileHandleCloseMinimum: NumberInt("250"),
    wiredTigerFileHandleCloseScanInterval: NumberInt("10"),
    wiredTigerMaxCacheOverflowSizeGB: 0,
    wiredTigerSessionCloseIdleTimeSecs: NumberInt("300"),
    writePeriodicNoops: true,
    ok: 1
} );
```

**New discovery**

When i drop the original index(built on a 6 digit string field ,say 688280, and i call it "code" which has a bad cardinality) ,and create a new one(built on a 17 digit time string,say 20211207150727460,and i call it "time" which has a good cardinality) ,the cpu usage drop significantly.

Thus , `I guess the situation has something to do with the Cardinality of the index . Or maybe the sequentiality of the inserted data(time field has a better sequentiality)` ?

Nevertheless , keepping the sequentiality of "code" matters for business query reason, so at the monent, i change the single field index to a composited index(add field _id to increase the cardinality and create a new one: code_1__id_-1). Check the cpu usage again , the result is of course not
as good as "none index" or "time index" , but it also decline to around 100%(compare to previous 300%-400% usage) and sometime spike to 200% for a few seconds.

Anyway,this is a temporary solution and i still don't get the "point". If anyone knows anything ,pls offer some help, thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

In general it is best you do the initial batch insert first and create the index in background later to keep your database still available during index creation:

```
   db.mycollection.createIndex( { code: 1 }, { background: true } )
```

Comment: thanks for you reply , but for my mongo version 4.2.2 , it seems whether am i set backgroud to true or not doesn't matter , see [index build process](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/#std-label-index-operations) . I had tried and still get high cpu usage

Comment: Also you may need to add some more memory for the index buid task , check this parameter: maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes  , default is 500MB for 4.2.2

Comment: what the output of top -H -p <mongod pid>  show you during index build?

Comment: Hi R2D2 , i had changed the parameter maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes to 2048, but still not working .